# How can I be sure that my app will work across most phones?

Tags: android, google-play

I recently built an app and while testing it across available phones I transferred it via ShareIt to another phone. It got installed but did not run. But the app worked when I tried installing from the Android Studio. Does this mean that such issues can happen on Play Store too?

Comment: It can.  But if it worked on the same phone from Android Studio, the problem is likely that either you have sideloading turned off, or a bug in whatever ShareIt is.

Comment: @Vanna Thanks, I'll be checking that.

Comment: @GabeSechan I just wanna make sure that the app will work when downloaded from Play Store.

Comment: @AdityaNigam Only way to be absolutely sure is to actually try it.  But have you checked and made sure that 3rd party sources are enabled on that device?  By default they're turned off.

Comment: @GabeSechan its turned on. Thanks, hopefully it will work. :)